# How to add .html end of URL

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm new with Phalcon PHP. I can't figure out how can I add .html to end of url for every page. I already looked up docs. Nothing related to this isn't in docs

Thanks,

Comment: You can do so in your web server's configuration with some URL rewriting. The real question : why would you ever want to do such ugly things ?

Comment: for seo, isnt it more friendy to seo ?

Comment: It should not be relevant for SEO. Look at stackoverflow, there is no .html and all questions are ranked very high.

Comment: If the first thing you think about when designing an app is SEO then you're doing it wrong, it feels even worse than premature optimization. Focus on creating a beautiful and usable app, and then think about SEO.

Comment: Static page content for seo cache increase by SE crawl ... Ref: [doordie.co.in/seo/160216](http://doordie.co.in/seo/160216)

Answer (score 1):

You can customise the routing parameter, e.g:

```
$router->add(
    "/documentation/{name}.{type:[a-z]+}\.html",
    array(
        "controller" => "documentation",
        "action"     => "show"
    )
);
```

would route  `/documentation/color.doc.html` to  showAction in DocumentationController with params `$this->dispatcher->getParam("name") === "color"` and `$this->dispatcher->getParam("type") === "doc"`

For further info please read the docs in http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html